# combination of adding and subtracting of digits for specific value in C

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

Let´s say a number is called happy if there is any combination of addition and subtraction of the digits, ​​so that the result is 42.
Example:
9999993, 999399 and 399999 is happy because 9 + 9 + 9 + 9 + 9 - 3 = 42
3783985861 is also happy because: 3 + 7 + 8 − 3 + 9 + 8 − 5 + 8 + 6 + 1 = 42

My idea:

- count how long the given number is
- count the combinations:  2^n combinations | n = number length
- for loop and check all combinations so that the result is 42 
  but how?????
- do it recursively. I can do it by adding all digits. But how to check all 
  combinations?

```
int isHappy(unsigned int aNum){

int count = 0;

while(aNum != 0){
    aNum /= 10;
    count++;
}

int nTimes = 1;

for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
    nTimes = nTimes * 2;
}

for(int i=0;i<nTimes;i++){
    ????
}

return nTimes;
}

int main(){

printf("%d", isHappy(999993));

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Each digit has two possible signs. Giving you a nice binary tree you can traverse and backtrack recursively.

Comment: An O(n^2) solution is possible using dynamic programming. Think about whether it is possible to get a particular addition/subtraction of first few digits. Create a 2d array indexed for number of digits and the result. (Edit: O(n^2) actually)

Comment: Just for fun, note that the number of digits in the base-*b* representation of an integer *x* is O(log *x*), for any *b*.  Thus, how you characterize the asymptotic complexity of the problem depends greatly on how you define the size of the problem.

Comment: That smells like homework. Read [ask], particularily about homework questions.

Comment: Contrary to OP, `9999993` is _not_ happy. (6 nines)

Comment: It is soo much easier to solve these problems with something like PROLOG or Haskell...

Comment: @chux Yes, you are right. There should be 5 nines like after because...

Comment: Note: About 21% of positive `int` are happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posts that are certainly homework can benefit with *some* guiding code, but not too much - difficult to strike that balance.

---

For each digit, there are 2 ways to go, add the digit or subtract the digit. [@Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44832205/combination-of-adding-and-subtracting-of-digits-for-specific-value-in-c#comment76645032_44832205).  This is a classic consideration for a recursive solution.  For an n-digit number, expect O(2**n) iterations.

[Other approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44832205/combination-of-adding-and-subtracting-of-digits-for-specific-value-in-c#comment76645207_44832205) may be more efficient.

Avoid hard coding 42

```
#define HAPPY 42
```

Make a helper function that passes in the number and the current sum and returns success status.

What should the terminating condition be?
How to do *some* of the work?
How to try various paths for the rest of the task?

```
int isHappy_helper(unsigned int aNum, int sum) {
  if (aNum == TBD) {
    return sum == HAPPY;
  }
  // Extract one digit from aNum  (how about the least significant digit?)
  int digit = TBD;
  // What is left in aNum once the above digit is removed?
  aNum = TBD;
  // Try adding and subtracting the digit with the sum
  return isHappy_helper(aNum, TBD) || isHappy_helper(aNum, TBD);
}
```

Call the helper function with a sum of TBD

```
int isHappy(unsigned int aNum) {
  return isHappy_helper(aNum, TBD);
}
```

Some test code

```
void isHappy_test(unsigned int aNum) {
  printf("%u %d\n", aNum, isHappy(aNum));
}

int main() {
  isHappy_test(0);
  isHappy_test(1);
  isHappy_test(9999993);
  isHappy_test(999993);
  isHappy_test(999399);
  isHappy_test(399999);
  isHappy_test(3783985861);
  return 0;
}
```

Expected output

```
0 0
1 0
9999993 0
999993 1
999399 1
399999 1
3783985861 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I now have another idea for a solution. I want to split the number in an array of digits and do some permutations.

Comment: Simple but nice idea to provide some test code in a homework-help answer. BTW, "O(2**n)": remnants of a misspent youth coding FORTRAN?

Comment: @DavidBowling ... and I miss the [3-way if](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vn9p/index.html) too.